# How to solve 2D Poisson equation for coordinate independent source?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

$$\frac{∂^2 u}{∂x^2}+\frac{∂^2 u}{∂y^2}=S(x)$$

Consider solution $u(x,y)$ in finite Cartesian domain $(0,L_x)\times(0,L_y)$.
The domain is subjected to the source of $S(x)$, which is only dependent on $x$ and well defined. For now, consider the boundary conditions to be fully zero Dirichlet.

I had tried the series expansion but it did not work well because getting Fourier coefficients demand integration for both $x$ and $y$ yet as source is only $x$-dependent, it vanishes to zero when I am integrating for $y$ coordinate.
Any clever trick to solve this?

Was also thinking about Green's function but the calculation on convolution is very tedious and therefore, am looking something else.

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "finite Cartesian domain"?

Comment: Not infinite. So we can just say domain is defined in specific region. For example, can say x=[0,Lx], y=[0,Ly].

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012777/2d-poissons-equation-with-constant-source-function-and-dirichlet-boundary-condi?rq=1) may help you.

Comment: See this [link](https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde302.pdf) that gives a solution for the Poisson equation in a rectangular domain.

Comment: @Gonçalo thx for the appreciation but that series expansion method only works for the source term dependent bon on x and y.

Comment: @K.defaoite Perhaps I really need to use Green's function.

Comment: Apparently you think that $\int_0^{L}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L}\right)dy=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$. The integral vanishes only if $n$ is even.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for your advise. I was in kind of a trouble because the actual domain was in fact, about x=[-ax, bx], y=[-ay, by], and it was the transient diffusion equation. With your tip, I finally managed to get the solution. Many thanks!